# How to prevent double interation of list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, key-value

I am trying to create text strings by populating from a json object string.

When I iterate through the list of dictionaries, the iterator doubles the string. How do I fix this?

Code so far:

```
import json

data = '''{
 "text": "aaa",
 "text2": "bbb",
 "data": [
   {
     "id": "1",
     "text": "Red"
   },    {
     "id": "2",
     "text": "Blue"
   }
 ]
}'''

data_decoded = json.loads(data)
data_list = data_decoded['data']
insertQuery  = "update "+ data_decoded['text'] +" set "
#print(insertQuery)
for pair in data_list:
   for k, v in pair.items():
       if k == data_decoded['text2']:
           where = ' \"' + k + '\" = \'' + v + '\''
       else:
           insertQuery = insertQuery + ' where \"' +k+'\" = \''+ v + '\''

   query = insertQuery + where  
   print(query)
```

Output:

```
update aaa set  where "id" = '1' where "text" = 'Red' "id" = '2'
update aaa set  where "id" = '1' where "text" = 'Red' where "id" = '2' where "text" = 'Blue' "id" = '2'
```

My desired result is for every key value pair the code prints one sentence, like so:

```
update aaa set  where "id" = '1' where "text" = 'Red'
update aaa set  where "id" = '2' where "text" = 'Blue'
```

Comment: Is it always `id` and `text`?

Comment: @Roelant yes that is correct

Comment: And why do you have `k == data_decoded['text2']:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but you can just access your dictionary items rather than looping over them :)

If you use `>= python 3.6`

```
query = ''
field = data_decoded['text']
for pair in data_list:
   query += f"update {field} set where id = {pair['id']} where text = {pair ['text']}\n"
```

Otherwise:

```
query = ''
field = data_decoded['text']
for pair in data_list:
   query += "update {field} set where id = {id} where text = {text}\n".format(field=field, id=pair['id'], text=pair['text'])
```

Comment: I had to change the quotes around like this: `query = ''
field = data_decoded['text']
for pair in data_list:
    query += "update {field} set where 'id' = {pair['id']} where 'text' = {data['text']}"
    print(query)`

Comment: output from the above code is as follows: `update {field} set where 'id' = {pair['id']} where 'text' = {data['text']}
update {field} set where 'id' = {pair['id']} where 'text' = {data['text']}update {field} set where 'id' = {pair['id']} where 'text' = {data['text']}`

Comment: Its the new shorthand for formatting the string introduced in python 3.6, the following two are equivalent: `a = 1; print('the number is {a}'.format(a=a))` and `a = 1; print(f'the number is {a}')`. Sometimes people used the `.format(**locals())` for this reason :)

Comment: Added the other formatting method, and also removed the `'id'` apostrophe, as far as I use SQL those are not required :)

Comment: I get error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` with the new code trying to figure it out